# Multiplication and Division of functions

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, numerical-methods

Suppose that you have two continuous functions, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.
Suppose that you have numerical approximations for these functions, stored a vectors, $f^*$ and $g^*$.

If I want to approximate $t(x) = f(x) * g(x)$, does that mean that I multiply the corresponding elements of $f^*$ and $g^*$? For example $t^*[1] = f^*[1] * g^*[1]$ ...etc

Likewise, If I want to approximate $q(x) = f(x) / g(x)$, does that mean that I divide the corresponding elements of $f^*$ and $g^*$? For example $q^*[1] = f^*[1] / g^*[1]$ ... etc.

Comment: I think t(x)=f(x)*g(x) will simple multiplication because in my study there was a question find out (f.g)x where $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\sin x$ so answer was $x^2\cdot\sin x$ and we also found out domain (f.g)x from $x^2\cdot\sin x$.and same in division case

Comment: @iostream007 can you please point me to a textbook or online lecture notes?